# segueing from collection view to detail view problems

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I'm slowly going out of my mind trying to replicate an iPhone photo gallery with a collection view segueing to a detail view and I want the detail view to have paging just like the photo gallery does. The code I have so far seems to load but then has an error. I have exemption breakpoints on and the breakpoint 1.1 crash point is the line self.imageView.image = img;. This doesn't say anything about the error on the log other than (lldb).

I was wondering if I can borrow someones genius to point out where I have gone wrong and perhaps correct it? I would also like to take a title for each image across to the detail view but didn't know how/where to add this in.

The code I have is:

```
#import "MarbleCollectionViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MarbleCollectionViewController () {

    NSArray *marbleImages;
}

@end

@implementation MarbleCollectionViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    marbleImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"arabescato.jpg",
                    @"bianco-carrara.jpg",
                    @"botticino-classico2.jpg",
                    @"Calacatta_Oro.jpg",
                    @"crema-marfil-3.jpg",
                    @"crema-valencia.jpg",
                    @"emperador-dark.jpg",
                    @"jura-beige.jpg",
                    @"nero-marquina.jpg",
                    @"perlato-olympo.jpg",
                    @"rojo-alicante_marbleGRP1.jpg", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return marbleImages.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *marbleImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    marbleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[marbleImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailView" sender:collectionView];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailView"]) {
        DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];
        destViewController.img = [marbleImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and the detail view is:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize imageView, img;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageView.image = img;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

A massive thank you for any help you can offer is in order and I really really do appreciate it.

Comment: You did not say which error you are getting

Comment: I have exemption breakpoints on and the breakpoint 1.1 crash point is the line self.imageView.image = img;. This doesn't say anything about the error on the log other than (lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a path to an image, not an image to your DetailViewController, so your viewDidLoad needs to be:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:img];
}
```

This should be a good lesson in naming -- don't call something an image (or img) if it's not one, it just makes for confusion. Call it something more descriptive like imageName or imagePath.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! Still not working though, says - Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

Comment: Finally getting an error report for it too - *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: @David, how is img declared in DetailViewController? It should be declared as a string. The range exception error is a different problem I think. What line does that error occur on?

Comment: img is declared like - @property(strong) UIImage *img; The error came after I was trying something different, I have since changed a few more things and am now getting nothing from the collection view. I have the file in my dropbox should you want to see the mess i've made!

Comment: @David, yeah, I'll take a look at it. What's the link?

Comment: @David, I found the source of your errors. It would be easier to tell you about them in a discussion. I don't think there's a way I can make that happen. We just need a few more back and forth cycles here to get the system to prompt me for that. Why do you have 2 different collection view controllers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30348/discussion-between-david-and-rdelmar)